# Ionic TextAreas getting too large

Tags: css, html, ionic-framework

I have some textareas in a ionic-framework-project that are nested in a list. The textarea is not shown fully. A part of it is out of screen.

```
<div class="list" style="width:100%;">
    <label class="item item-input" style="max-width:100%">
        <span class=input-label>Description</span>
        <textarea required></textarea>
     </label>
</div>
```

what happens is that the width of the textarea is getting too big, span.width+textarea.width > 100%.

If I manually set the textarea width down a little bit, it is shown 100%.

I set the max-width of it's parent to 100%, so it shouldn't get larger, but it does.

How can I prevent this behaviour and let the textarea not grow over the screen.

[image]

Comment: Can you try overflow:none; on the textarea?

Comment: this is unfortunately not applied, because it gets overwritten and i dont know by what

Comment: I set overflow to none, but this doesn't work.no changes.

Comment: does anyone could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="list" style="width:100%;">
    <label class="item item-input" style="max-width:100%">
        <span class=input-label>Description</span>
        <textarea rows="4" col="12" required></textarea>
    </label>
</div>
```

Try this.
Restrict textarea with 'col' attribute.